# second dropdown is not fill when selecting fisrt dropdown value

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have two table ,

1. state where StCode, StateName

2.district where DistCode, StCode, DistrictName

My code for first Drop down

```
<td><label for="studentstate"></label>
      <select name="studentstate" id="studentstate">
        <?php
                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                if(!$con)
                    {   
                    die('could not connect:'.mysql_error());
                    }

                    mysql_select_db("db_loan",$con);

                    $sqlstr="select StCode,StateName from state";

                    $result=mysql_query($sqlstr);

                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['StCode'].'">'.$row['StateName'].'</option>';

                    }
                    echo $sccode=$row['StCode'];

            ?>
      </select></td>
```

Now i have try following for second dropdownlist where i want to show district name

```
    <div id="result">
        <input type="button" value="Reload"></input>
          <select name="studentdist" id="studentdist">
          <?php 

          $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                    if(!$con)
                        {   
                        die('could not connect:'.mysql_error());
                        }

                        mysql_select_db("db_loan",$con);

                        $sqlstr="select DistCode,DistrictName from district where StCode='$sccode'";

                        $result=mysql_query($sqlstr);

                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['DistCode'].'">'.$row['DistrictName'].'</option>';

                        }
                    //  echo $sccode=$row['DistCode']; 
          ?> 
          </select></td>
</div>
```

Now if i what i should do for reload my div when select first value from drop down list

Please if you know please tell me how to do it without using ajex or jquery

After read suggestion from mirza i have updated my code as follow but still there it is not working

```
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $("#studentstate").change(function() 
    {
      $("#studentdist").load("pag1.php?choice=" + $("#studentstate").val());
    });

    </script>


    <body>
```

Comment: This is for your reference. [Check it out](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_drop_down_list.php)

Answer (score 1):

you need some JQuery Basic to do this task

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
  $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
});
</script>
```

getter.php replace with your php page name and it will work

Comment: i have to write this in script tag ? can you update answer with tag?

Comment: and in first -choice and second-choice i have to write name of first and second drop down list?

Comment: replace your select list id with first and second

Comment: i think i have make changes as per your suggestion but still it is not works